# No module named 'feature_engine.missing_data_imputers'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

```
from feature_engine.missing_data_imputers import RandomSampleImputer
```

When I tried to run this command I got an error "No module name
'feature_engine.missing_data_imputers'"

However, I have installed feature engine using the command "pip install feature-engine". It showed me I have successfully installed "feature-engine-1.4.1"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from feature_engine.imputation import MeanMedianImputer
```

I had this issue and I solved it by referring the [documentation of feature-engine](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/0.6.x_a/imputers/RandomSampleImputer.html).